# In Rails how I add a "helper" method to an attribute / column?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

Let's say we have an table called "Items" and a column named "name" and one named "quantity".

Then let's say we have an instance of item like this:

```
@item = Item.first
```

On this instance you can call methods, for example:

```
@item.name.present?
@item.quantity.is_a?(Integer)
```

How would I go about adding my own method to all columns, for example if I wanted to call:

```
@item.name.custom_method?
@item.quantity.custom_method?
@item.name.custom_method_2(:xyz)
@item.quantity.custom_method_2(:xyz)
```

So I'd like to add methods to all columns attributes, each one and do a custom thing with it. I've seen some gems to it and Rails does it with dirty for example and adds `changed?` to columns/attributes.

Comment: Those are not "custom methods" for a column. They are methods implemented on the return value. For instance: `@item.name` likely returns a `String` and `present?` is implemented for the `String` class. If you want to add a method to ALL Objects you could add it to the `Object` class (but please don't). `ActiveRecord::Dirty` does not add `changed?` as a method for return values (because this would not be possible) instead it defines a new method `XXXX_changed?` through meta-programming.  If this is what you are interested in please clarify the use case and maybe we can help.

Comment: Ah I see, thank you for the explanation. I was mistaken about rails dirty. The answer below is very helpful and I think what I'm looking for so I'm going to mark that as the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can define what's called *attribute methods* which will in turn define methods for all attributes:

```rb
# app/models/model.rb

class Model < ApplicationRecord
  attribute_method_suffix "_is_custom?"

  private

  def attribute_is_custom? attr
    "#{attr} is custom."
  end
end
```

```rb
>> Model.first.name_is_custom?
=> "name is custom."
>> Model.first.id_is_custom?
=> "id is custom."
```

*https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/AttributeMethods.html*